# MediaPlayer service get stopped onBackPressed

Tags: android, service, media-player

I'am starting a MediaPlayer Service via an Activity, exactly with a button:

```
startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class));
```

My Service Executes in onCreate the MediaPlayer

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    prepareMediaPlayer(); //prepares the MediaPlayer, setDataSource and so on
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Service");
}
```

I can get out of the activity with the homebutton and the stream plays fine, but if I get back via backButton the stream stops. And begins to start again. With other DataSource. 
Can you help me why?
I got no error!

Comment: Solved it myself with a foreground service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an foreground service (with `setForeground()`) solved it.

Comment: How to create a foreground service?